# Methods That Return Values Quiz

Tags: java, method-call

I am super new to programming and I had a question on a quiz and the output answer was 36. I don't understand how that outcome came out of this code.

```
public class Method {

    public static int method(int number) {

        int result = 0;
        while ( number > 0) {
            result += number % 10;
            number = number / 10;           
        }
        return result;
    }       

    public static void main (String[] args) {
        System.out.println(method(9999));
    }
}
```

Comment: What was your answer, and how did you arrive at it?

Answer (score 1):

Clearly within this code the part we need to look at is the while loop, this is the area of interest because it's where all of the calculation occurs.

```
while(number > 0){
    result += number % 10; 
    number = number/10; 
}
```

So the first line within the loop will add a value to the result:

```
result += number % 10;
```

The % operator in Java and many other languages can be thought of as a remainder of division, hence we are adding the remainder of division by 10 to the result.

9999 / 10 = 999 remainder 9.

So result has 9 added.

Then we call:

```
number = number / 10;
```

In Java when dividing an int we do not consider the remainder, so 9999/10 = 999.

And then we repeat. So essentially we are adding up the digits of the number.

9 + 9 + 9 + 9 = 36.

Answer (score 0):

Even if you are new at programming, you could try to use an IDE like Eclipse.

Using an IDE you can use the breakpoints and follow the code line by line and the variable line by line. So you will understand what happens.

You could create a watch expression that will show on a tab the variable to you or use the inspect to do this.

A video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=drk_ldaRMaY